# Service account for cloud function serverless framework

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, serverless-framework, service-accounts

I’m trying to deploy a google cloud function using custom runtime service account through serverless framework. So How to specify service account name in serverless.yml? For google cloud function

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't support custom runtime. Do you have any links to documentation describing what you are trying to do ?

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add?project=<project-name>

From the cloud function console, we have option to select service account under Runtime, Build, connection and security setting, when create a function.

So I assume that, there shoud be an option to provide the runtime service account in serverless.yml for serverless framework deployment.

Comment: What is this  serverless framework deployment you are mentioning ? is is https://www.serverless.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, we can use serverless framework to deploy a cloud function.
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/functions

Comment: There does not appear to be a method to specify the Functions service account. Try creating a feature request.

Comment: As @JohnHanley mentioned this is not a GCP issue, you gotta ask the people behind serverless.com to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is possible to [specify a service account for a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#individual), it would seem that the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) doesn't yet support specifying it in their configuration.

There is an [open issue for this feature](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/issues/161) on GitHub as well as [an open pull request](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/pull/154). Unfortunately neither have moved forward in quite a while.